# Cant access variable inside function

Tags: php, laravel, function, laravel-5

In a model I got a scope function with 3 parameters, `$query`, `$sort_by` and `$sort_dir`, I can access them before the join function, but for some reason I can't access inside the join function.

Why? Am I missing something?

```
public function scopeOrder($query, $sort_by=false, $sort_dir='ASC'){

    if(!$sort_by)
        return $query;

    var_dump($sort_dir); //prints 'ASC'

    return $query->join('product_translations', function($q){

        var_dump($sort_dir); //variable undefined <----- ERROR

        $q->on('product_products.id', '=', 'product_translations.product_id')->where('product_translations.locale', '=', 'de');

    })->select('product_products.*')->orderBy('product_translations.name');

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `use` keyword:

```
return $query->join('product_translations', function($q) use ($sort_dir)
```

---

**Explanation:**

This is an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). So, the variable loses its scope inside that function. You need to make the variable available for that function using `use` in PHP

Comment: Wow... Such a retarded failure, thank you. Time to go sleep I guess :p

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the parameters to the  anonymous function, you are only passing `$q`, any variable can't be seen inside the function unless it was passed to it using `use($var)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use variables which within your function, which is another scope than where the variable is defined, you have to use a `use` statement:

```
return $query->join('product_translations', function($q) use ($sort_dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `use` keyword to access them in your function